# Richtextbox library

Tags: javascript, richtextbox

I would like to use a JavaScript richtextbox library in my application.  What library does Stack Overflow use, and is it available for me to use?

Comment: does **not** belong to meta. he is asking to use in his application, not to understand how so works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a **[WYSIWYM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYM)** editor. See **[WMD editor](http://wmd-editor.com/)**

See a demo **[here](http://wmd-editor.com/examples/splitscreen)**.

Answer (score 1):

SO uses WMD: http://github.com/derobins/wmd